# Убрать одинаковые значения из списка следующие друг за другом

Tags: python

В списке ниже иногда между разными значения (например 115.2 и 116.9) встречаются одинаковые друг за другом (напр. 114.2 и 114.2). Нужно из одинаковых оставить последнее, а предыдущие одинаковые заменить на nan.

```
[nan, nan, 115.4, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.41, nan, 115.41, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.44, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan]
```

Как решить это в одну строчку?

Что должно выйти:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.41, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.44, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan]
```

Comment: А что за `nan`, кстати? Это строка `'nan'`? Это `None`? Это `np.nan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd
a = [nan, nan, 115.4, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.41, nan, 115.41, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.44, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan]
s = pd.Series(a).fillna(method="bfill")
s[s == s.shift(-1)]=nan
a = s.tolist()
```

теперь `a`:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.41, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.44, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Учебные задачи нужно решать самому. Но поскольку задачка интересная, то предложу решение. Только непонятно, кто такой `nan` тут, допустим это `numpy.nan`. Решение дико неэффективное, но в одну строчку, как просили:

```
from numpy import nan
arr = [nan, nan, 115.4, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.41, nan, 115.41, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.44, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan]
print([x if x == nan or arr[::-1].index(x) == i else nan for i,x in enumerate(arr[::-1])][::-1])
```

Вывод:

```
[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.4, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.41, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.44, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 115.43, nan, nan]
```

Для выяснения, что элемент последний я использую `.index`, но он ищет с начала, поэтому всё приходится переворачивать - и исходный список, причём два раза, и результирующий тоже. А дальше легко - смотрим, что `.index` даёт тот же индекс, что `enumerate` для текущего элемента, значит это самый первый такой элемент.

Comment: А у вас число 115.43 пропало на выходе

Comment: Не пропало, оно 3-е с конца, на месте )

Comment: Там два таких числа - одно посередине где то - оно пропало)

Comment: А, точно, я пропустил условие "следующие друг за другом", да. Тогда надо ещё подумать )

Comment: `x == nan` это всегда `False`.вместо этого можно попробовать использовать `x is nan`